# Deploy Nextjs project from Gitlab to Azure Static Web Apps with Bazel

Tags: docker, next.js, gitlab, azure-web-app-service, bazel

I was trying to deploy a Nextjs project from the Gitlab to Azure Static Web Apps, and this project is built and tested by Bazel.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
$CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - WORKSPACE
  - package.json
  - .gitlab-ci.yml
  - web
    - tsconfig.json
    - next.config.js
    - BUILD
    - pages
      ...
  - <other unrelated projects>
  - bazel-out
  - bazel-bin
```

The build rule for nextjs server:

```
next(
    name = "server",
    srcs = [
        "//web/pages",
    ],
    data = [
        ...
    ],
    next_bin = "../node_modules/.bin/next",
    next_js_binary = "//:next_js_binary",
)
```

In my local env, the command to run the nextjs server is:

```
bazel run //web:server_start
```

To build and deploy on the static web apps, here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
- build
- deploy

variables:
  DEPLOY_OUT: bazel-cd-out
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/bazel-bin/web/.next'
  OUTPUT_PATH: ''
  SKIP_APP_BUILD: 'true'

build_nextjs:
  image:
    name: cockroachdb/bazel:20230316-060229
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: build
  script:
    - bazel clean
    - bazel --output_base $DEPLOY_OUT build //web:server_start
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bazel-bin/web/.next
  cache:
    key: nextjs
    paths:
      - $DEPLOY_OUT

deploy_nextjs_prod:
  stage: deploy
  image : registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - echo "App deployed successfully."
  environment:
    name: nextjs_prod
    url: <url>
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
  dependencies:
    - build_nextjs
```

It first builds the nextjs server and then pass it to the deploy stage, but here is the error when deploying:

```
Skipping step to build /builds/.../bazel-bin/web/.next with Oryx

Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (builds/.../bazel-bin/web/.next). 
Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.

If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 
'app_location' in your deployment configuration file points to the root of your application.

If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists 
in the build output directory.
```

I tried to skip the build phase when deploying by adding in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  ...
  OUTPUT_PATH: ''
  SKIP_APP_BUILD: 'true'
```

But it did not work. I am not sure if this is the correct direction.

I am new to NextJs+Bazel, but not new to Bazel. Any example of how this project should be correctly deployed?

Comment: Can you try if this is [useful](https://medium.com/@bamnet/using-bazel-on-gitlab-ci-fe59cad2db50)